# Textures after soldify?

Tags: modeling

I have created a hairstyle. When I try to soldify it to get a thicknes i can only see blurred rims. How to change it without unwrapping uv maps once again ?[image]

Comment: If you apply the modifier, then you can just select the faces that are showing incorrectly and manually unwrap and align those.